# Restore deleted purchase order

Tags: purchase-order

Is there any way, we could restore a Purchase Order that was accidentally deleted?
when I was editing the organizer tab of a specific purchase order, I was supposed to delete the task but I clicked the delete for the Purchase order instead.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to recover a delete order. Only solution was to restore the database from backup. If that contain your order data otherwise there is no solution.

Comment: Thanks. We are able to restore the PO data from the back-up file.